Why do some of the directories in `/run/systemd/` have permissions 600?
I read that assigning write permissions to a directory is pointless unless you also enable execute permissions (allowing the user to "enter" the directory and write to it). But I ran the command
sudo find / -perm -u+w -not -perm -u+x -type d

and found several directories on my system that write permissions without execute:
/run/systemd/propagate/systemd-userdbd.service
/run/systemd/propagate/systemd-udevd.service
/run/systemd/propagate/systemd-oomd.service
/run/systemd/propagate/systemd-resolved.service
/run/systemd/propagate/auditd.service
/run/systemd/propagate/dbus-broker.service
/run/systemd/propagate/chronyd.service
/run/systemd/propagate/iio-sensor-proxy.service
/run/systemd/propagate/rtkit-daemon.service
/run/systemd/propagate/power-profiles-daemon.service
/run/systemd/propagate/accounts-daemon.service
/run/systemd/propagate/switcheroo-control.service
/run/systemd/propagate/systemd-logind.service
/run/systemd/propagate/upower.service
/run/systemd/propagate/polkit.service
/run/systemd/propagate/ModemManager.service
/run/systemd/propagate/NetworkManager.service
/run/systemd/propagate/gssproxy.service
/run/systemd/propagate/bluetooth.service
/run/systemd/propagate/uresourced.service
/run/systemd/propagate/fwupd.service
/run/systemd/propagate/passim.service
/run/systemd/propagate/fprintd.service

All of these directories have permissions 600. For example:
> sudo ls -la /run/systemd/propagate/chronyd.service
total 0
drw-------.  2 root root  40 Jun 24 19:37 .
drwxr-xr-x. 26 root root 520 Jun 24 19:49 ..

What's the purpose of this? If the write permission isn't doing anything, wouldn't 400 be consistent with the principle of least privilege?
This is Fedora Kinoite 40, if relevant.

If I understand correctly, the purpose of /run/systemd/propagate/* directories is to act as mount points for dynamic bind mounts, for services running in their own mount namespaces. This explains why the x permissions are not needed.
When operating as root with restricted capabilities (specifically, if the process setting up the bind mount for the service in question has already given up the CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE capability), I think the kernel may only allow mounting to directories that are writeable to the process requesting the mount. This could explain why the write permissions are present.
